How can I replace, in the javascript <collection.style.width="37.4%";>, the fixed value 37.4% by a variable?
On a blog-type webpages (like on this page), photos are presented mainly in groups of two or four (in 1 or 2 lines of photos). Each photo container is centered and has a width calculated in such a way that portrait photos do not look bigger than landscape photos, with a last visual adjustment. To do that, I want to set the width of the photos container in accordance with preset classes.
Five styles are used and I want a calculation to determine their respective "width" value.
I want to replace a fixed width (37.4%) by its calculated value: the variable Width1ImagePortrait, assigned to the class class1imageportrait. So, instead of using a fixed value (37.4%) stylesheet for the page
html
<style> .class1imageportrait {width: 37.4%; height: auto;} </style>

end html
I use a javascript to use the getDocumentsByClassName() Method
in which I substitute the variable Width1ImagePortrait to the value 37.4. Adding the double quote and the % unit, the script boils down to
script
let width1ImageLandscape = 49.9%;  

A block of photos "landscape" is given 49.9% of window width
let imageRatio = 4/3;  

Length to width ratio of photos displayed
let Width1ImagePortrait =   Math.round(10 * Width1ImageLandscape / imageRatio) * 0.10);  

A block of photos "portrait" is given 37.4% (3/4 of 49.9) of window width
let W1ImagePortrait = '"' + Width1ImagePortrait + '%"';       

Adding the double quotes and %
let myBunch = document.getElementsByClassName("class1imageportrait");
    
for (let i = 0; i < myBunch.length; i++) {
    myBunch[i].style.width = W1ImagePortrait;
    }            

End script
In the above script, the line
myBunch[i].style.width = W1ImagePortrait;
  

fails on my computer (it refuses to understand the variable it is given), while the line
      myBunch[i].style.width = "37.4%";
      

which does not contain a variable, would work

How do you fail? What does it mean?

put an extract of the parts of code that are causing you problems, but first of all read the guidelines for using this site, because your question here is unacceptable in its current state. help section, asking a good question, do a minimal reproducible example,Here's a question checklist you might find useful...

Why does W1ImagePortrait contain double quotes? It's like myBunch[i].style.width = '"37.4%"';. The extra quotes are probably a problem.

Thanks jabaa. Your suggestion works. My apologies to all of you for my poor respect of forum rules (not intentional).

Please don't add the answer to your question.

My thanks to @jabbaa for clarifying my question. Well done !
